# How to delete everything after the next colon

Tags: notepad++

```
Test123:Password:7 AUG 2018
Test123:Password:7 AUG 2018
Test123:Password:7 AUG 2018
```

I want to remove everything after the second colon for all lines,

I tried `^([^:]*.[^:]*):.*$` and it didn't work,

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression seems good, I suspect the problem is you have not told notepad++ (I asume you are using that editor since it is present in the tags) that you want to keep the group you have defined, and not the whole match (which in your example happens to be the whole line).

In the dialog you should see:

Search:

```
^([^:]*.[^:]*):.*$
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

The second part means you want to keep the first group of characters, or in other words, erase the rest. In this case the regular expression you defined means: replace all the lines that has more than two ":" with whatever is before the second ":" occurrence

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^:]+:){2}\K.+$` OR `^[^:]+:[^:]+\K:.+$` if you want to remove the second colon
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (?:       # start non capture group
    [^:]+   # 1 or more any character that is not a colon
    :       # 1 colon
  ){2}      # end group, must appear twice
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  .+        # 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Test123:Password:
Test123:Password:
Test123:Password:
```

OR (depending on used regex)

```
Test123:Password
Test123:Password
Test123:Password
```